# IntellIJ - Too much space between border and code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, config, intellij-14

I'm having my code far from the border, where the line numbers are. I'd like to have like half of what it is now, but I wasn't able to find how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow Draku.

This is the place for gutter icons, which can be helpful for projects. If you don't need it, it's in View->Active Editor->Gutter Icons.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I got rid of those already because we don't use them too much. Anyways, if i need them any time, i know where they are now. Thank you for the help!